# WordPress Loop and Single post same template file

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to have the loop and single post within the same template. Basically my client wants there to be a transition when the link is clicked in the loop to display the single post.

I haven't come across any way to do this so I'm guessing not.

Comment: a single.php page has a loop inside of it, i think you are confusing loops and single posts

Comment: I know, I'm asking if it's possible to have the have the loop and single function within the same template.

Comment: then im not following what exactly do you need? its possible to display both posts & pages on one page or post...

Comment: Yes, if you can combine loop.php and single.php into a single template file. So if you see the list of posts, click a post, and it displays the post without changing pages.

Comment: I think what you want is to have two loops. The URL will make the content of the loop to be the single post and it will load the single post template. But you also want to have a loop representing an archive on that page, is that right?

Comment: @user1272433 you can do that with one loop and ajax and you can click on a post and it will display the post content on top of the other posts...